# How I Override Body Tag In Ctrl+Shift+I Inspector

Tags: html, css

I have some Html code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>ControlShiftI Example</title>
</head> 
<body> 
Enter UserName <input type="text" name="user"><br> 
Enter Password <input type="password" class="password-input" name="pass">
</body>
</html>
```

that I am running on browser after ctrl+shift+i in inspecor I want to override some other code in complete body tag.
in above after I dont want to see this body tag code some override code i want see.
is this possible?

Comment: So how will you detect it if they open it up via the menu? It is not going to make any difference. For decades people have been asking questions on how to hide code in the browser and the answer is basically the same, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not possible.**

## Hide Javascript

If your concern is having a tidier HTML because Javascript code takes too much space, just `<script src="externalFile.js"></script>`

If your concern is you want to hide your code, because you don't want others to read it and understand it, you could minify and obfuscate the code, for example with UglifyJS. However the inspector can undo the minification by prettifying the code. Obfuscation however cannot be totally undone depending on techniques used.

## Hide HTML

If this question is not about javascript and you want to reduce the number of html lines:

```
<object data="externalHTMLFile.html"></object>
```

or

```
<iframe src="externalHTMLFile.html"></iframe>
```

There are also other ways.

But you cannot simply hide some html from the inspector or remove the ability from the user to open the external HTML file and read all the HTML.

Comment: inspector formats the html code so not really going to help.

Comment: @Attersson But how to do this?

Comment: @epascarello It can prettify minimized code but obfuscating can hardly be undone depending on the operations performed. The code will be unreadable

Comment: It is HTML the OP wants to hide.... What you are suggesting makes no sense since it is formatted in the browser developer console. There is zero lines of JavaScript in the sample code.

Comment: So, an html line in html? Isn't this tagged as javascript? He wants to hide a javascript line inside the html.

Comment: I edited my answer and addressed all concerns. This is the best I can do. The question is not formulated in the best of ways, itself.